# how can i have dynamic name of a array variable in php?

Tags: php

I used this but my array show blank.

```
foreach($page_data->result() as $text){ $i++;
echo $name="text".$i; //this line print ok.
$$name=array();
echo $$name['content']=$text->$content; //this line print ok.
print_r($text1);
} print_r($text1);
```

here i am tying to name the array dynamically as text1,text2,text3.......
but when i print $text1 it shows me a blank array.

can any one help me out with this.

Comment: It's better to rewrite completely. What do you need?

Comment: Use an array! `$texts[$i]['content'] ...`

Comment: You're incrementing the index before you echo the contents of the variable, so if you only have 1 result, it will try and access an undefined index.

Comment: @deceze i can use 3-d array .
and i will get the result what i want.But why not this method when this syntax is available of $$variable_name.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a syntax ambiguity. `$$name['content']` is understood as:

```
${$name['content']}
```

I.e. the name of the variable is supposed to be the value of `$name['content']`, which obviously doesn't exist, which actually leads to an error if you'd enable error reporting. You can solve this with:

```
${$name}['content'] = $text->$content;
```

However, you *really* should solve this by using an array instead of variable variables:

```
$texts[] = array('content' => $text->$content);
```

Comment: thanks ,buddy.
Thats what exactly i wanted know (problem in my code),
I genrally use array for this.

Answer (score -1):

You're incrementing the index before you echo the contents of the variable, so if you only have 1 result, it will try and access an undefined index, you are also re initialising the name array every time you pass through the loop, you should not do this

```
Results
------------------
Num     Content
0       I am a text post
```

If these were the results returned and you wanted to point to index `i`, then when your loop goes through this would happen:

```
i = 0;
i = 1;
assign values to name array
```

As there is only one result this would then happen

```
 Results
------------------
Num     Content
0       I am a text post 
-       -                  <----- i = 1 (null pointer exception?)
```

This would be why no values are showing in your array, try change your code to this:

```
// Declare i to point at the 0 index
$i = 0;
$name=array();

foreach($page_data->result() as $text){ 
  $name[i]['content']=$text; 
  $i++;
}
```

Your name array will no add the text content to a new index with each pass of the loop, i.e. if you had 2 results

```
$name[0]['content'] = "This is a text post";
$name[1]['content'] = "Here is another post";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks @alex for your reply,I got the point how can i do this,but i did not get you on what is problem in my code,coz i checked in all the way,no initializing problem as you told.